# Combining Curve modifier with Follow Path constraint

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, constraints

Is there a way to deform a mesh along the curve but also move the object along the curve?

- if I add a `Follow Path` constraint with `Follow Curve` option enabled, my object doesn't deform;
- if I add a `Curve` modifier, it deforms but I can't offset it;
- if I add both constraint and modifier I can't make them to behave the way I want;

Is it possible to achieve what I want without using `Armature`?

The only workaround I found so far is modifying my object pivot point + using `Curve` modifier, but this won't work for me: I want to have several linked objects along the curve.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! `Displace` modifier before the `Curve` modifier with the same axis:

[image]